# How to tell the PhpStorm IDE that a constant exists?

Tags: phpstorm

The IDE (PS-117.65) is complaining that some of constants aren't defined.

I've defined them in a loop in another file. Can I put a doc comment at the top of this file to inform it about the constants? The usual `/** @var` and `@global` syntax doesn't seem to work for constants.

Comment: You usually define "constants" in a header file, which you can "include()" or "require()" in your PHP module

Comment: @KirkWoll: Yes. I'm looping over some data and defining them as constants. Perhaps it's not "proper", but that's the way it's being done.

Comment: @paulsm4: I'm using a framework. In frameworks you usually don't have "pages" that include headers and or/footers. You've got an "engine" which pieces everything together for you, so that your PHP files are light and don't have any includes in them. Unfortunately, this is confusing for IDEs.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Since when am I not allowed to ask about IDEs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no known to me PHPDoc comment to do that.

But you can "fake" them -- create some `const.php` file and place it **anywhere** in a project (you can even place it in separate folder outside the project and attach it as External Library or as separate Content Root).

In this file -- define those constants with in a normal way: `define("CONST_NAME", "value");` The "value" part can be anything (as long as types are matching -- useful for inspections/code analysis) -- it really depends where those constant will be used (e.g. if they are used in include/require statements, then it may be beneficial to have some real (or close to it) values there).